# Android: reload activities (singleTask) not working

Tags: android, reload

I've got this problem:

I have three activities (every activity is defined in manifest as SingleTask): A, B and C.

1. I call from A to B --> B is created.
2. I call from B to  C --> C is created
3. I recall B from activity C --> activity is *resumed* (**not re-created**).
4. Finally, from B I want to recall activity C but in this case, activity C is *re-created*.

Why? What I want to do is the following thing: I need to create activities (A, B and C) only one time (and not depending from which activity I call the other).

Comment: When you say recall, do you mean hit the back button? If so, that's expected behavior. When you hit the back button from an Activity it is finished (destroyed).

Comment: Please post your manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Try FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT in intent while launching activity check out http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT